# Sort an array in a specific way

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, function-definition, qsort

> Write an efficient function in C language that receives an array `A`
> of natural numbers and their amoun as `n`. The function must rearrange
> the array `A` like this:
>
> In the left part all the even numbers will be sorted in ascending
> order and in the right part all the odd numbers will be descending
> down.
>
> The function must run on the order of n·log(n).
>
> It is forbidden to use an auxiliary array but we can use functions
> like :
>
> quicksort , binarysearch , partition , merge_sort..
>
> For example:
>
> `A={6, 8, 8, 10, 20, 5,1}`: the function `A={ 1, 20, 5, 6, 8, 8, 10 }`
> will rearrange the array

I tried to order the whole array using quick sort and then running all over the elements, putting the even numbers first and then counting how many even numbers there is. After that, using the evencounter starting one step after it tried to put the odd numbers and tried to sort them in descending order.

The complexity should be n·log(n) so I don't know whether running all over the elements is the right thing to do.

Comment: *"quicksort , binarysearch , partition , merge_sort.."* ---> where do these functions reside? Are you supposed to write them?

Comment: *"I tried to order the whole array."* ----> Post the code.

Comment: You only need to sort once. If two values to be compared are odd and even, the even one is first. If they are both even, the lower value is first. If they are both odd, the higher value is first.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is enough to use standard C function `qsort`.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmp_numbers( const void *a, const void *b )
{
    unsigned int x = *( const unsigned int * )a;
    unsigned int y = *( const unsigned int * )b;

    int result = ( int )( x % 2 ) - ( int )( y % 2 );

    if (result == 0)
    {
        enum { Even = 0, Odd = 1 };

        switch (x % 2)
        {
        case Even:
            return ( y < x ) - ( x < y );
        case Odd:
            return ( x < y ) - ( y < x );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return result;
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    unsigned int a[] = { 8, 1, 6, 3,  4, 5, 2, 7, 0,  9 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf( "%u ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    qsort( a, N, sizeof( *a ), cmp_numbers );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf( "%u ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is

```
8 1 6 3 4 5 2 7 0 9
0 2 4 6 8 9 7 5 3 1
```

Otherwise you could for example write a function that split an array in two partitions and sort the partitions separately.

Pay attention to this lone

```
int result = ( int )( x % 2 ) - ( int )( y % 2 );
```

without casting to `int` the result of expression will be `unsigned int` (the type of x and y) and never can be negative.

If you want to have an array of signed integers then apart from other changes from unsigned int to int in this statement use standard C function `abs`

```
int result = abs( x % 2 ) - abs( y % 2 );
```

Comment: Well, the enum is nice for visualising what's going on, but actually I'd have prefered a simple `if(x%2) { return ...; } return ...;` or even a ternary operator; maybe: `result = ( y < x ) - ( x < y ); return x%2 ? -result : result;` – just for completeness...

Comment: Minor:  `int result = ( int )( x % 2 ) - ( int )( y % 2 );` deserves a descriptive comment.